# Посмотреть вывод запущенного процесса в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Есть какой-то длительный работающий процесс, запущенный Cron-ом, который по мере своей работы выводит в консоль информацию.

Как можно в консоли "временно подключиться" к этому процессу, чтобы посмотреть, что сейчас он выводит?

Answer (score 2):

## ...

> ps -auxw | grep test.sh
>
> **strace -p 2222  (PID)**

## ...

> test.sh >> log.sh.txt

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы можно было подключиться к процессу нужно чтобы его вывод был направлен в какой-нибудь терминал, к которому можно подключиться и посмотреть. Это сложно, да и не зачем. Самый простой способ - это просто перенаправит вывод вашей команды в файл и в любой момент посмотреть этот файл.

```
/home/dat/scripts/cron.out > /path/to/log.txt 2> /path/to/error.txt
```

Отслеживать прям во время выполнения можно будет с помощью команды

```
tail -f /path/to/*.txt
```